# How to classify EEG and ECG signals

Tags: machine-learning, research, data-format

I'm a student and a beginner on [Physionet](https://physionet.org/). What is the best method to classify EEG and ECG signals: KNN or SVM? And how can I do it with matlab? Should I convert the .dat files to .mat or just extract features to build my matrix for training and for testing? I don't know how to begin to develop my classifier?

Comment: I think current state-of-the-art for EEG datasets of seizure classification is convolutional neural networks: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/mirowski-mlsp-08.pdf

Comment: Hi
thank you for the answer, and is it the same thing for the ECG signals?
the convolutional neural network, we can implement int with matlab?? means I can use the same algorithms used to extract features and to build my dataset vectors ??
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a bidirectional LSTM?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(1, 12)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
```